# Highlight duplicate rows in a multiindex dataframe and export to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python code that uses a multiidex dataframe, which is exported to Excel. What I would like to implement is a function that, in excel, highlights the duplicate rows in the table.

An example of the result I want is the following:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **C** | **D** |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

The rows (1,1) should be highlighted, due to the fact that they are duplicates.

Here's what I have of the code, so far.

```
header=[['A', 'B'],
        ['C', 'D']]
 
merge2.columns=header

total_style = pd.Series("font-weight: bold;")
merge2.style.apply(lambda s: total_style)

path = r"test.xlsx"

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=merge2.droplevel([1], axis=1).columns)
df2 = merge2.droplevel(0, axis=1)

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', merge_cells = True, startrow=1)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the second-to-last line, the function works successfully and automatically saves the format to excel

```
df2['Duplicate'] = df2.duplicated()

df2.style.apply(lambda x: ['background-color: yellow' if (x.Duplicate == True) 
                          else ('background-color: white' if (x.Duplicate == False) else '') 
                          for i in x], axis=1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', merge_cells = True, startrow=1)
```